# How can I tell whether it is a call to a static method or an instance method?

Tags: java

If the below code is the only  provided information, how Can I determine whether it is a Static or an instance methods?
`foo.bar(x, y, z);`

Comment: Not possible ..

Comment: Even if you had `Foo foo = new Foo()`, still not possible because that would show up as a compiler warning and `static void bar()` could still be called

Comment: It does not do that on my normal system with normal Eclipse 2021-06, @OneCricketeer

Comment: @Alan "Normal" is subjective. IntelliJ definitely highlights it as a problem (although, that may also be a plugin). Also, compiler warnings are shown at compile time, not any specific IDE

Comment: The IDE chooses what level to apply to a problem that the compiler finds.  One level is "ignore".  By normal all I meant was that I had updated Eclipse and I had not applied any changes that would block reporting of such a warning if one got issued by the compiler, or any extreme changes; not many changes to preferences at all.  Yes, the compiler finds them at compile time, but the IDE might not show it.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, it would be an instance call, because `foo` starts with a lower case letter.

But convention is broken often and so can't be depended on for certainty.  So there could be a class accessible to the code call `foo` instead of `Foo`.

So there is no definitive answer.

Comment: You can also call static methods on an instance.

Answer (score 2):

The way to tell is if this is a `static` or instance method call is to do the following:

1. Find the declaration of the `foo` variable (or class) to determine its compile time type.
2. Examine that type's code to find the matching method `bar` methods.
3. Perform the method overload resolution based on the static types of the argument expressions.
4. Finally, check if the resolved `bar` method is `static`.

An typical IDE can do this automatically, assuming that the respective definitions are available.

A Java compiler will also do this, so you *could* use `javap -c` to examine the compiled bytecodes for the class; see @rzwitteserloot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170885/139985).  However, you then have the problem of figuring out which `INVOKE...` instruction corresponds to that method call.  (And there is the binary compatibility issue that he notes.)

---

However, if you *only* have that 17 character snippet of source code, it is not possible to distinguish `static` and instance method calls.

We cannot be sure that `foo` is a variable.  (It could be the name of a class ... where the programmer has ignored Java style conventions!)

Even if we *know* `foo` is a variable, we still don't know if this is invoking an instance method, or invoking a static method via an instance reference.  The latter is allowed by the JLS<sup>1</sup> but it is definitely bad style.

---

<sup>1 - For example, see [JLS 15.12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1): *"if the invocation mode is static ..."*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

When writing code, you know. The compiler can't compile the code without knowing this. A method is encoded in a class file as an `INVOKESTATIC` or `INVOKEVIRTUAL` bytecode instruction, and the instruction includes the so-called fully qualified binary name of the method, which includes not just `bar`, but also the type `bar` is from, its (erased) param types, as well as its return type. It's something like:

```
INVOKESTATIC #1, #2
```

where 1 2 and 3 are refs to the constant pool, which are then refs to constant strings, which contain something like:

```
#1: com.whatever.Foo
#2: bar(IZLjava/langString;)V
```

That last thing isn't gobbledygook and also isn't the result of a cat walking over a keyboard. That's bytecode-ese for `void bar(int, boolean, String)`. (I = int, Z = boolean, V = void, L = object type).

Clearly then the compiler has no idea what strings it should put in the constant pool unless it already knows, **at compile time**, what `bar` actually is. This works out: If you don't have the type that `foo` belongs to on the classpath, it just doesn't compile.

Contrast to languages like python or javascript, where you can just roll your face over the keyboard pretty much and it won't fail until you get to that line. Java doesn't work that way.

So, how would you know? You'd know.

If it's just a convenience thing, well, get an IDE. They'll tell you. For example, eclipse renders static calls in *italics* and non-static calls without italics.

If you're worried that the method is static today but you're intrigued if it ever becomes non-static tomorrow, well, um, I guess don't worry, in the sense that if you don't recompile, the code won't work. The `INVOKESTATIC` is baked into that class file, if the target type does have a `bar` method but is updated to a newer version and there the `bar` method is all of a sudden no longer static, the INVOKESTATIC call will fail at runtime with an `Error`. In general, if you mix and match versions that aren't backwards compatible, code won't run. That's by design, pretty much.